# SQL group by subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
select title_id, shared_task_id from tasks_task order by title_id
```

The results are like so:

```
title_id    shared_task_id
1           99217
1           NULL
4           18873
4           18874
4           18875
4           NULL
4           NULL
4           NULL
```

I want to find all `shared_task_id`s that have more than one `title_id`.

Here would be an example. Using the below data:

```
title_id       shared_task_id
1              100
2              100
3              105
3              NULL
4              110
5              NULL
6              120
6              120
6              120
```

The query would return:

```
title_id       shared_task_id
1              100
2              100
```

Because this is the only entry with the same shared_task_id with a different title. What would be the correct query here?

Comment: Could a given shared_task_id have twice the same title_id? What would be the output then?

Comment: It shouldn't include those. Please see the updated sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a self join is the way to go.

```
select distinct t1.title_id, t1.shared_task_id
from mytable t1 join mytable t2 on t1.shared_task_id = t2.shared_task_id 
and t1.title_id <> t2.title_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tasks_task t1
JOIN (
  SELECT shared_task_id FROM tasks_task
  WHERE shared_task_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY shared_task_id
  HAVING count(DISTINCT title_id) > 1
) t2 ON t1.shared_task_id = t2.shared_task_id
```

Output:

```
| TITLE_ID | SHARED_TASK_ID |
|----------|----------------|
|        1 |            100 |
|        2 |            100 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e86e/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title_id, shared_task_id
FROM myTable
WHERE shared_task_id IN (
    SELECT shared_task_id
    FROM myTable 
    GROUP By shared_task_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Updated:

```
SELECT title_id, shared_task_id
FROM myTable
WHERE shared_task_id IN (
    SELECT shared_task_id
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT title_id, shared_task_id FROM myTable ) A 
    GROUP By shared_task_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```